# Why does Source Film Maker crash when loading cp_badlands?

Tags: source-filmmaker

Whenever I try to load cp_badlands into Source Film Maker, it crashes, randomly.

I've tried restarting multiple times, and I will only try reinstalling as a last resort, as it takes too long. The map is important, too, so I can not simply use another one.

Is there any reason why a specific map would crash Source Film Maker? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: The edit has clarified the problem enough for me to answer this question, if it is reopend. TLDR, that particular map is already known to simply not work with source filmmaker. I would recommend reopening, so the answer can be upheld for future users.

Comment: @Timelord64 This question has been reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it appears that the map **cp_badlands** is well known to cause issues with the Source Filmmaker. There has been several posts about it in the Steam forums<sup>[1](http://steamcommunity.com/app/1840/discussions/0/666825525497405591/)</sup> <sup>[2](http://steamcommunity.com/app/1840/discussions/0/558746089726345522/)</sup> <sup>[3](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1840/discussions/0/627456486456947709/)</sup> <sup>[4](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1840/discussions/0/620703493324163776/)</sup>.

While users suggest that it relates to the word "bad" included in the name, and perhaps triggers filtering that changes the actual command being run, this is more likely to be speculation based off further issues with a other badlands maps. It is worth keeping in mind that **Source Filmmaker is still in open beta**, and is likely to contain bugs, both minimal and game breaking.

---

> **[This Steam forum thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3234834) has a comment from *Mr_Zo* that might provide insight:**
>
> I was never quite sure what caused this. The only main difference between cp_badlands and arena_badlands, is the former is bigger. So obviously there is something in cp_badlands that causes the crash (Keeping in mind that SFM is based on a much older TF2 engine version than the current).
>
> The sdk_content does provide "sdk_cp_badlands.vmf". I've tried compiling that, but it still causes a crash.
> If there is an area that you need to use in cp_badlands that isn't in arena_badlands, you can try cutting out that section from "sdk_cp_badlands.vmf" and delete everything else.

---

While this does not fix the initial problem, it gives us further insights into why the issue might be happening, and alternate ways to work around the map.